# Perfect square or cube

Tags: number-theory, factorial, square-numbers

There is series like $N = 3! + 4! +\cdots+ 64!$. It is asked whether it is perfect square or cube .  How to identify Whether $N$ is perfect square or cube for any big factorial or for sum of factorial ?

Comment: It's not divisible by $4$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown ...but it is divisible by $2$. Slick.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define $a_n$ as
$$a_n=3!+4!+...+n!$$
Rearrange this sum as
$$a_n=3!(1+4+4\cdot 5+4\cdot 5\cdot 6+...+4\cdot5\cdot ...\cdot n)$$
Since $3!=6$ is not a perfect square or divisible by a perfect square, in order for $a_n$ to be a perfect square, the sum $1+4+4\cdot 5+...+4\cdot5\cdot ...\cdot n$ must be divisible by $6$. Note that all terms including and after the $4\cdot 5\cdot 6$ term are divisible by $6$, so the whole sum is divisible by $6$ if and only if $1+4+4\cdot 5$ is divisible by $6$. It is **not** divisible by $6$, so $a_n$ cannot be a perfect square.

Of course, this makes the assumption that $n\ge 6$, but you can check the cases $n=3,4,5$ for yourself since they are only finitely many.

Answer (score 1):

the number is of form 8k+6. a perfect square cant be of this form.

Comment: This looks like a perfectly OK answer to me. It does not give all the details; so what? It is a very strong hint, like many other answers on this site.